# CSS cross browser compatibility on Ubuntu

Tags: css, ubuntu, cross-browser

I'm currently working in web development and my default desktop is Ubuntu and I'm kind of happy with the setup and applications I got going. But I need to test web pages for cross browser compatibility while still being on Ubuntu.
I have gone through hell trying to get IE7 or IE8 (with wine) to run on ubuntu and when they finally worked they were very buggy and the graphics/scrolling was insanely slow.
Of course there is the option of virtual box but again, too much GBytes just to run a small application!

So to all the CSS gurus out there, how can I continue with my beloved Ubuntu and still deliver a good quality (tested) page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:**

Update for freshness:
I now use the paid service from [browserstack.com](http://browserstack.com) to provide the multitude of different browser testing environments via flash tunnelling.  I'm a paid user, but there is an initial free trial period.  browserstack has freed me of the need to run the windows os on my machines in any form, virtual image or otherwise.  Since it also allows tunnelling, I can host the site on my local machine but still test in browserstack browsers.  I consider the monthly fee money *very* well spent.

**End Edit**

### Various options I have tried, including "the final solution": free downloadable windows testing OSes from microsoft

I've tried a number of the options below, but virtualbox may be your best bet for full & complete testing, especially because in a professional capacity you often have to test ie8, ie7 -and- ie6.  Which gets tricky with only a single os installed.  So in order of simplest and most shallowly testing to most complex and most fully testing:

### browserlab.adobe.com

- A newer, interesting online solution is: [browserlab.adobe.com](http://browserlab.adobe.com).  It's actually very specific and fast compared to browsershots.  It only gives you screenshots, but it's a great first step.  So I do recommend that for purely visual (and thus relatively shallow) testing.

### Browsershots.org

- And while [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org) is also something that you **should use for an overview experience** of what users might see, you really can't get by without the real browsers for javascript and behavior testing (instead of just display & rendering testing that browsershots provides).  The delay before you can see the images is also killer.

### Dual booting into windows

- Another that I've tried is dual booting, I work 99% of my time in ubuntu, and I have windows installed & available to dual boot into.  Not a fast way to test, but if you don't have any other way to access ie, it should work for at least the latest version.

### Remote desktop-ing over to a running windows box

- Before I mention the "covers-all-the-bases" option, another useful possibility is to set up a windows machine and boot it up and connect to it via remote desktop so that you can work from one machine and test from both.

### The final solution, using virtualbox

- Finally, the mother of all solutions, using virtualbox:

Luckily (I know you said you didn't like the virtualbox solution, and I know it's an annoying setup process, but...) Microsoft provides available-for-a-year-or-more virtualmachine distros with different versions of ie pre-installed, available without the need for a license for a year or so before you'd have to update the virtualmachine, @
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

### Installing a virtualmachine from microsoft's freely available browser testing images

Because this guide to setup on ubuntu is no longer available in full anywhere else, just in case you or someone else actually need it I feel compelled to include the actual details of the install process that were suggested to me on the ubuntu forums and worked when I went through them.  I apologize for their length.  Courtesy of the now anonymous original poster on the ubuntu forums:

### Free Access to Microsoft Browser Compatibility Virtual OSes, Install Steps for Ubuntu

> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1097080 (Ed: I can't find this thread online any more)
>
> HOWTO: run IE6, IE7, IE8 on Linux in
>   VirtualBox You need: virtualbox, qemu,
>   wine
>
> Code: apt-get install virtualbox qemu
>   wine
>
> Download the free(!) Microsoft
>   Internet Explorer Application
>   Compatibility Check VPC Images here:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en
>   (Note: you don't have to download the
>   full pack, you can cherry pick
>   specific combinations of XP/Vista and
>   IE6-8)
>
> Extract the VPC image(s) with wine
>   (double-click). (Note: it might take a
>   while before the first window shows
>   up)
>
> Turn the VPC image(s) into (a) VMWare
>   image(s) (which is/are readable by
>   VirtualBox): qemu-img convert -f vpc
>   image.vhd -O vmdk image.vmdk
>
> Setup a new VM in VirtualBox, using
>   the vmdk image as an existing disk.
>   Boot it, you will see the Windows boot
>   progress bar and ... it will BSOD
>   shortly after.
>
> Fixing the BSOD:
>
> The BSOD is caused because the virtual
>   Windows tries to load processor
>   drivers for the wrong processor (it is
>   not running on VirtualPC proc, but on
>   VirtualBox proc). Or something like
>   that... We need to force Windows not
>   to attempt to load drivers for the
>   processor (it doesn't need any proc
>   drivers, because it's all virtual
>   anyway). Start safe mode by
>   (frantically) hitting F8 at Windows
>   boot and choosing safe mode.
>
> Ignore all the 'New hardware' detected
>   warnings (we will deal with those
>   later). Start a command box and run
>   the following command to disable the
>   loading of processor drivers:
>
> Code: sc config processor start=
>   disabled (note the space between '='
>   and 'disabled'!)
>
> Restart the virtual Windows, it should
>   now boot all the way to the Windows
>   Desktop.
>
> Now just when you think you can start
>   browsing the web with IE, you will
>   find out that the virtual Windows
>   needs to install the drivers for the
>   AMD PCnet NIC, which are located on
>   the Windows install disk. Fortunately
>   for those without a Windows install
>   disk, there is another way :)
>
> Download AMD PCnet drivers here:
>   http://www.amd.com/us-en/ConnectivitySolutions/ProductInformation/0,,50_2330_6629_2452%5E2454%5E2486,00.html
>
> Make an iso file containing the
>   drivers. I used Brasero for
>   simplicity. Choose to create a Data
>   Project, add the zip file (or the
>   unzipped files, saves you a step in
>   Windows), create the iso. No need to
>   burn an actual cd!
>
> Stop the virtual Windows, edit the
>   settings in VirtualBox: mount your
>   brand new iso.
>
> Start the virtual Windows, when it
>   asks to install the drivers for the
>   PCnet nick, point it to the (unzipped)
>   drivers. Et voila! You have teh
>   innernets! (Now you can also try to
>   install the other drivers it complains
>   for, but it's not really necessary)

The image README says the image will expire after about a year.  In my experience the system gets hobbled against multi-hour use, but is still usable for the kind of short periods that you might want when booting up to test a website.  At worst you might have to go through these steps again, so be sure to put them somewhere where you can find them again after a year or so.

Comment: Ooooh, those images look fine. +1.

Comment: Virtual box it is then,
I will give the Microsoft Distros a try.

PS. I already have Windows 7 on dual booting but this is for gaming purposes but I can't just restart my machine every time I want to test a CSS line :)

Comment: VirtualMachines are the way to go! In most modern companies the development environment is not public accessable, which means you cannot use browser screenshot services. Plus, they cannot reproduce behaviours (:hover, interaction). Emulators are always just emulators, and even they are buggy or not perfect. You can get licences of Winxp for 10€ legally on ebay. A macosx licence is also available for under 100€. If this is your job, then you should spend this. and you will have a perfect setup. And you can always close, reset or update any VM.

Answer (score 5):

I think setting up a virtual machine (Virtualbox or VMWare or...) with a proper Windows will be your only (local) option.

I you don't have one, buy a used Windows XP license. XP is cheap (around 20-30 euros here in Germany, for example) and all relevant versions of IE run on it. Home edition is enough. No need for Windows 7 or anything.

You could install [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) on that to get all the IE versions on one OS. IETester has flaws and is not always 100% reliable in what it renders, but for a general CSS compatibility check it should be okay.

I've never tried IE using Wine, but even trying to *imagine* the combination gives me goose bumps :D

Comment: yeah, I think I'll have to set up a VirtualBox.
I try to get me the lightest Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a copy of Windows you could install it in a virtual machine ([Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is a good, free option).  Or if you don't mind a lot of lag time and publicly exposing your web pages you could use a service like [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this on Ubuntu or anything but windows - but this seems to be a pretty good testing system over the web.

http://spoon.net/browsers/

however, I think your best result would be to use a VM if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately every testing link on that page gives "this option is not available for your device" in ubuntu.  Perhaps it is windows only?

Answer (score 1):

I have to add my voice to those opting for VirtualBox.

VMs are the only way to get an accurate representation of how IE platforms behave. They also allow you to keep your main Linux install free of WINE and IE gunk, which is otherwise always troublesome and fragile. (Especially if you're trying to run multiple IEs, which is unreliable and inaccurate even under Windows).

They're not necessarily *that* big, if you take care to prune the unneeded features, turn off swap, compact the disc image and so on. My XPSP3 test image is just over 800MB.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to install all this stuff as I wanted to move forward quick.

I found public AWS images with pre installed browser that you just can start and use.

http://www.hens-teeth.net/html/products/cross_browser_testing.php

If you already have an AWS account this will take you only 5 min. Make sure that you enable the RDP port on the incoming traffic in your security group.

As I use ubuntu I was looking for a way to connect from it to MS Win.
I'm connection on to them via remote desktop. 
The way to go here is **rdesktop**, a command line utility for Windows Remote Desktop. (sudo apt-get install rdesktop)

If you feel like a GUI use **tsclient**. It's very close to the windows version.

From a work flow perspective I develop for Chrome in Ubuntu first, then have a look at the  other browsers via browserlab.adobe.com.
After that I start my new AWS instance to debug.

The small AWS Windows instance is a $0.12 per hour (http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing). I can work for a long time on that before it's worth installing all this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

CrossBrowserTesting.com works from Linux.  Allows you to access Mac, Windows, and Ubuntu configurations and all the browsers loaded on them via vinagre vnc client.